# Implement order pages with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I wanna implement a order page, but it's so hard...

The system is in portugues, for others reasons, sorry about this.

My view:

```
conta/pedidos/index.html.erb

<h3>Meus pedidos</h3>

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Data do pedido</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @pedidos.each do |pedido| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to pedido.id, pedido_path(pedido.token) %></td>
        <td><%= pedido.create_at.to_s(:long) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My controller:

```
conta/pedidos_controller.rb

class Conta::PedidosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_usuario!
  def index
    @pedidos = current_usuario.pedidos.order("id DESC")
  end
end
```

My model:

```
pedido.rb

class Pedido < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pessoa
  has_many :itens, class_name: "ItemPedido" , dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :enderecos

  before_create :gerar_token

  def gerar_token
    self.token = SecureRandom.uuid
  end

end
```

And the error:

```
ArgumentError in Conta::PedidosController#index
No association found for name `enderecos'. Has it been defined yet?
```

Please, what I make?

Comment: I can't see an error but it's difficult to know because is in portugues :/ just one recomendation and maybe the solution for generate some querys to database is better to create an scope in the model and after call it in the controller example: scope :desc, order("pedidos.perdidos_at DESC") and after that call it into your controller like :  @pedidos = current_usuario.pedidos.desc regards !

Comment: If you don't have both a model and a database table for `enderecos`, you'll need to create those. If you do have that model, you need to add its association to pedido.rb (e.g. - `has_many :enderecos`), assuming it is associated in some way with that model.

Comment: Hi man, this is github of my projetct: https://github.com/eltonsantos/loja_produtos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :enderecos` in pedido.rb. It's not mentioned anywhere in the provided code. Can you simple comment/remove it?

If it's need, then you need to set association for it: may be `has_many :enderecos`

Comment: Hi man, this is github of my projetct: https://github.com/eltonsantos/loja_produtos

Comment: Have this error now:

ArgumentError in CarrinhosController#checkout
No association found for name `enderecos'. Has it been defined yet?